# What is UNIX domain socket authentication?

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, authentication

Could someone explain in simple terms what 'UNIX domain socket authentication' is and how it works? Thank You

Comment: It's a way to securely send Unix credentials (pid, uid, gid) over the socket. It works by sending special ancillary messages of type SCM_CREDENTIALS with sendmsg(). The kernel will check if the sending process has rights to these credentials.